# Setting $PATH via a command with tox

Tags: python, tox

Currently using `tox` to test a python package, and using a python library (`chromedriver-binary`) to install `chromedriver`.

This library creates a script (`chromedriver-path`) which when called outputs the PATH where `chromedriver` is installed. The usual way to use this is to run:

```
export PATH=$PATH:`chromedriver-path`
```

I've tried the following without success in `tox.ini`

```
setenv= 
  PATH = {env:PATH}{:}`chromedriver-path`
```

This errors as expected:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver': 'chromedriver'

Implying that the setenv command is never called/run.

```
commands=
  export PATH=$PATH:`chromedriver-path
```

This fails with:

> ERROR: InvocationError for command could not find executable export

How do I make this work?

Comment: Commands run in subprocesses. Subprocesses can't change their parents' environment.

Comment: Can you have `chromedriver-path`'s output in the environment (under *any* name) *before* you start `tox` at all? If you put `export chromedriver_path="$(chromedriver-path)"` in your `.bash_profile` (or similar as appropriate for platform &c, to have it exported before `tox` is ever started), then you'll be able to specify `{env:PATH}{:}{env:chromedriver_path}` in your `tox.ini`, assuming the syntax you gave was otherwise correct.

Comment: The script is created via the `pip` installation of `chromedriver-binary` via tox's `deps` so it doesn't exist before `tox` runs.

Comment: Would a bash command in `commands` work? i.e something like `bash -c 'PATH=$PATH:\`chromedriver-path\` py,test ...'`

Comment: Sure, that could work. I'd go with `bash -c 'PATH=$PATH:$(chromedrive-path); exec "$@"' _ py test ...`, assuming `py test ...` is what you'd otherwise run. (Caveat: I know bash and Python, but not Tox; that said, the point above is that you want to keep dynamic components out of the argument that directly follows `-c` to the maximum extent possible to avoid shell injection attacks and other nastiness).

Comment: (backticks in shell are bad form -- they don't nest well, they change the behavior of backslashes, and they haven't been required literally for decades -- `$(...)` syntax has been standardized ever since the 1992 publication of POSIX.2).

Comment: Running it just now - if it succeeds I'll let you know and you can write up an answer for me to accept. (and yes, $() is good - I was thinking it was `${}` and was worried that `tox` would grab that!)

Comment: Yes, that seems to work - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commands can't change their parent processes' environment variables, and thus can't change the environment variables of subsequent commands launched by forking that parent; they can only set environment variables for themselves or their own children.

If you were able to collect the output of `chromedriver-path` *before* starting `tox`, this would be moot. If it's only available in an environment tox itself creates, then things get a bit more interesting.

One approach you can follow is to wrap the commands that *need* this path entry in a shim that adds it. Consider changing:

```
commands=
  py test ...
```

to:

```
commands=
  sh -c 'PATH=$PATH:$(chromedrive-path); exec "$@"' _ py test ...
```